# BlueImp jQuery FileUpload GitHub marked as readonly/archived?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, primefaces, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

The BlueImp jQuery File Upload GitHub project has been marked **"This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only.".**

See: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

But there has been no explanation or post from the developer.  No succession or continuity plan. The developer states that Stack Overflow is the official means of support for this plugin, so I am posting here since I can't post on GitHub to ask as its read-only now. Any insight from anyone or the developer would be great as we use this plugin heavily in PrimeFaces.

Comment: If we cannot find out if there is any follow up, shall we fork it and at least patch security issues?

Comment: I think we may have no choice but to do that or find a project who has forked it.

Comment: I had a look but I (Google) could not find a maintained fork

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that as the project is archived the author probably isn't supporting it anymore and so likely isn't going to be monitoring stack overflow to answer questions anymore. According to github they haven't contributed in a few months. It's license is open source and very permissive so if you use the code a lot you should probably consider forking it and taking over supporting it. You could also always reach out to the author through their home page https://blueimp.net/

Comment: Thanks David. I have tried to reach him through his email contact on BlueImp with no response.  I have no problem if someone wants to stop supporting an OS project but usually they try and hand it off to others first or at least post a reason on their project before just archiving it.  Its very strange.